# API to read admin drive share settings

Tags: google-drive-api

i am looking for an API to read admin drive share settings. Could not find any reference to reading share settings via an API

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive apps can manage permissions and [sharing settings of files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing). The Permissions collection provides apps the ability to read, update, and delete permissions for users, Google groups, Google Apps domains, and the public.

In addition to managing permissions through the API, apps can display a standard Google Drive sharing dialog to let users share files. Each permission in the Google Drive API has a role. A role defines what users can do with a file.

Every permission of a file or folder has a type. The type is the scope of the permission, and determines which users have a role. Permissions with types user and groups also have an emailAddress. Permissions with type domain have a corresponding domain property that specifies the domain name.

For additional information on manipulating permissions, see the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Drive API v2 [about.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) returns a `domainSharingPolicy` attribute which tells you if the user is allowed to share files outside their domain. So far Drive v3 does not have an equivalent.